# Is space not truly an empty vacuum but instead made up of densely packed particles of matter and antimatter?

Tags: space, matter, antimatter

In the livescience.com article [Superpowered Chinese Lasers Could Soon Rip Open Raw Vacuum](https://www.livescience.com/61562-laser-china-rip-vacuum-antimatter.html) I read that quantum electrodynamics states that the vacuum of space isn't empty, rather it's made of densely packed particles of matter and antimatter that cancel each other out.

As I understand it, if matter and antimatter touch they aren't simply cancelled out, they are annihilated/converted into radiant photons of gamma radiation.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: rip open raw chinese vacuum? densely packed vacuum which is annihilated? erm how do they shoot it? wrong forum.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There is no such "market sharing" deal between the sites, it wouldn't be even very liked by top SE hierarchy. If there would be, the question shouldn't be closed, instead it should be migrated there (what would be the best IMHO). Until then, only the local rules should decide if a question is on-topic or not.

Comment: @peterh I can't translate your comment into English.   FWIW questions on many sites are regularly closed with the recommendation to  migrate elsewhere.

Comment: Vacuum can appear to be densely packed with VIRTUAL particles, when tested in a certain way. Key word here is virtual. They don't really exist. To make them actually exist you'd have to supply their energy yourself. It's a bit like pointing at the desert in California City and saying "a lot of houses could exist here" - sure, if you bring in the contractors and build them up yourself.